# How to debug a cordova plugin with your phone?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I use Weinre to get a console from my phone. But on Javascript errors with plugins (contacts, geolocalisation etc...) I get nothing....

I don't know how to push on the console every javascript errors.

How to easily debug your javascript which use a plugin present only on your device ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you building for iOS or android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Console Plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) to debug your code in iOS, android, windows phone, etc.

Install the plugin using: `$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console`

Then its as simple as using `console.log(...);` in your javascript files.

If you want to log your geolocation you can do:

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    console.log(position.coords.latitude);
    console.log(position.coords.longitude);
};

var onError = function(err) {
    console.log(error.code);
    console.log(error.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

Then, when you build your app, and emulate, look for this log file in your project:

```
.../platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately I'm looking for a way to catch Javascript errors without the console.log option .